# linux wireless driver coding (ath9k): which API to use for reconfiguring channel type (b/t HT20 & HT40) on the go?

Tags: linux, types, driver, wireless, channel

I've been revising linux wireless driver (ath9k) to implement notify channel width action frame.

One thing need to be done is that change STATION's channel type between HT20 and HT40 without interrupting data transmission.

What I can do now is switching between HT20 rates and HT40 rates, but not channel type. For AP side, ieee80211_set_channel_type() works when called in function ieee80211_rx_h_action(). But on STATION side, I couldn't find a proper function within which to call ieee80211_set_channel_type(), and all my try caused kernel panic. Even calling ieee80211_set_channel_type() exactly the same way I do with AP on STATION side will crash system also.

Could anybody give some hint on possible API choice to change channel type between HT20 and HT40 on STATION side, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the linux-wireless mailing list material.  Please make sure you include the change you have made (choose one approach that you think would be the best) and the resulting backtrace.  My gut feeling you are calling a function that expects process context from softirq context.